# Problema con rutas en php mvc

Tags: php, mvc

estoy empezando con PHP siguiendo el patrón MVC y estoy haciendo una web para gestionar productos. El problema que tengo es que llamo a los controladores desde diferentes sitios de la web y esto me genera problemas en cuanto las urls. Por ejemplo, tengo una clase, controlador y vista referente a los productos, y aparte también llamo al controlador Productos desde el index.php y me da fallos. Si alguien ha tenido el mismo problema y/o me puede aconsejar un poco a como usar las rutas en MVC se lo agradecería mucha. Gracias.
Dejo por aquí los archivos:
- Estructura del proyecto:

[image: Estructura proyecto]

- Dirs.php:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Index.php, hago la llamada al controlador, aquí no se presenta ningún error:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Noticias.php, que también llama al controlador para mostrar noticias, igual que en el index.php, pero como no están en el mismo directorio, me da este error:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Y por último el archivo noticiaController.php, que llama al archivo noticiaModel.php para instanciar la clase Noticia:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Y la clase noticiaModel.php, que llama a la clase conexion.php: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resumiendo, el problema que tengo es que trato de llamar al controlador desde el index y desde otro archivo del view, y me da error. Espero que alguien puede ayudarme un poco porque no se que hacer. Muchas gracias de antemano compañeros.

Comment: Las rutas siempre son o bien absolutas o bien relativas, si fueras mas especifico o añadieras código se te podria ayudar, pero no me queda claro si te refieres a rutas como mencionas en el titulo o url como mencionas en la explicación

Comment: Perdona por no ser específico. Me refiero a la llamada de los archivos, es decir, include y require.

Comment: Pero si no pones el fallo es imposible ayudarte, para usar el controlador desde cualquier sitio tienes que instanciarlo y antes cargarlo ya sea usando namespace o include o require, en la ruta intenta cargar desde document root hacia adentro, tambien puedes usar _DIR_ y moverte hasta el controlador, p definir conatantes con. La ruta de cada una de tu carpeta

Comment: Recuerda que el separador de rutas es la barra normal `/` y no la barra invertida, procura usar ese separador en tu código PHP aunque pruebes en un XAMP bajo Windows. En Windows PHP convertirá automáticamente las barras `/` en las rutas por las `\` que usada Windows en sus rutas. Sin embargo, si usas `\` en cualquier otro sistema operativo, será considerado como un carácter más del nombre del archivo, no como separador de rutas,

Comment: Si pero la barra normal me da problemas, ya que dirname(__FILE__) muestra la ruta en con '\', y por eso tuve que poner la barra invertida. Aunque lo he cambiado por la / normal ahora mismo y no me presenta ningún error adicional, así que lo dejare como dices. Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error lo tienes en noticiaModel.php ya que estás incluyendo con una ruta relativa el archivo dirs.php que se encuentra en otro directorio como si estuviera en el mismo. Has puesto ./dirs.php cuando debería ser ../dirs.php ya que noticiaModel.php está dentro de la carpeta Models aunque la mejor opción es usar una constante de PHP que hace referencia al directorio donde está el fichero actual:

```
include_once(__DIR__.'../dirs.php')
```

Comment: Cierto en parte. Lo he cambiado y ahora funciona el noticias.php, pero el error que me aparecía en noticias.php, ahora me aparece en index.php.

Comment: Pon el error completo

Comment: Este error me aparece ahora en el index.php:[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqSMI.png

Comment: [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqSMI.png

Comment: No veo el error en index.php. Son las mismas imágenes

Comment: En efecto, es el mismo error pero ahora en el index.  [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjQMa.png

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar la constante  __ DIR __  que es el directorio del fichero: include_once(__ DIR __.'../dirs.php'); ? (No sé cómo poner el nombre de la constante correctamente). Aquí tienes la explicación: http://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Si, lo uso en el archivo dirs.php, puedes verlo en 2ª imagen de mi pregunta.

Comment: Ya pero me refiero a usarlo en el resto, donde incluyes precisamente el fichero dirs.php (noticiaController.php y noticiaModel.php)

Comment: Si, pero en el archivo dirs.php hago precisamente eso. Este archivo lo llamo desde todos los archivos que tengo que hacer llamada a otros archivos.

Comment: Si pones en noticiaModel.php y en noticiaController.php: include_once(__ DIR __.'../dirs.php'); en lugar de include_once('../dirs.php'); ¿Qué ocurre? ¿Sigue dando error?

Comment: No me da ningún error y me muestra bien los datos. Muchas gracias por la ayuda compañero. He hecho esto en noticiaController.php y noticiaModel.php y parece que funciona. Seguiré con el resto de la aplicación a ver si no tengo más problemas con las rutas. [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOWqc.png